# How to remove accents in column names with Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

How to remove accents in column names. Below the schematic showing the columns.

```
root
 |-- Canadá: string (nullable = true)
 |-- México: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Lituânia: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Quênia: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2633310/3238085  Use this library to sanitize your column names list and then apply the names. https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use unidecode package to achieve this.

```
pip install unidecode
```

I set up a dataframe looking like this:

```
+------+------+--------+------+                                                 
|Canadá|México|Lituânia|Quênia|
+------+------+--------+------+
|     1|     2|       3|     4|
+------+------+--------+------+
```

You can achieve what you want by first extracting the column names as a list using `df.columns`. You can then iterate over that list and use `df.withColumnRenamed(currentName, newName)` to change the column name.

```py
for col in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(col, unidecode(col))
```

As you can see the accents have been removed.

```
+------+------+--------+------+                                                 
|Canada|Mexico|Lituania|Quenia|
+------+------+--------+------+
|     1|     2|       3|     4|
+------+------+--------+------+
```